Why does `expect` on a `navigateByUrl` spy require the use of a RegEx matcher?
This works:
const routerSpy = spyOn(TestBed.inject(Router), 'navigateByUrl');
const thing = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.list .list-group-item'));
expect(thing).not.toBeNull();

thing.triggerEventHandler('click', new Event('click'));

expect(routerSpy).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(jasmine.stringMatching(/\/thing\/1/), jasmine.any(Object));

This does not:
...
expect(routerSpy).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith('/thing/1'), jasmine.any(Object));

The latter results in a weird string comparison error:
Expected $[0] = /thing/1 to equal '/thing/1'.
Can anyone explain this?

Element is a basic <a [routerLink]="['./thing', thing.id]"....

I'd also be interested to know why routerLink attributes don't use navigate, even though their syntax are identical...always felt an odd thing for the Router devs to do.

FYI: You can use spy.calls.argsFor(n)[0] to grab the actual UrlTree arg and call toString on it yourself, if you must stick with string comparisons and don't want to write a helper function to convert from string to regex.

The Jasmine.stringMatching seems to work if you give the input as a UrlTree or a string, this explains why the test case passes.

The accepted types for navigateByUrl are string | UrlTree so you are providing a string, but when you use routerLink to navigate, it is navigating using UrlTree. The solution is to create a URL tree and test it, but the jasmine string matching is the easiest method.
it('test 2', () => {
  const router = TestBed.inject(Router);
  const routerSpy = spyOn(TestBed.inject(Router), 'navigateByUrl');
  const thing = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#child'));
  expect(thing).not.toBeNull();

  thing.nativeElement.click();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(routerSpy).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(
    router.createUrlTree(['/thing/1', {}]),
    jasmine.any(Object)
  );
  console.log('after expect');
});

Stackblitz Demo
Also the navigate function, under the hood calls navigateByUrl.
Sample Debug Code:
  navigate(
    commands: any[],
    extras: NavigationExtras = {skipLocationChange: false},
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    validateCommands(commands);
    return this.navigateByUrl(this.createUrlTree(commands, extras), extras);
  }


The process makes sense. I'm asking more about how jasmine is comparing the UrlTree, and why it shows up without quotes. Their public docs (https://angular.dev/api/router/UrlTree) don't explain anything about the internals.
